# Is this a possible bug in 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter' when trying to eager load?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, jdbc, jruby, jrubyonrails

We have the following model:

**payment.rb:**

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :currencies

  default_scope :include => :currencies
end
```

We are using `default_scope` to eager load the currencies. When we run this we get the following error:

```
[2012-03-22 21:43:25] ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
/home/me/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7@my_project/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/associations/preloader/association.rb:88:in `associated_records_by_owner'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615:in `each'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7@my_project/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/associations/preloader/association.rb:85:in `associated_records_by_owner'
...
```

The problem can be found in:

**Line 88 and 89 in [association.rb (github link)](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/preloader/association.rb):**

```
...
owner_key = record[association_key_name].to_s

owners_map[owner_key].each do |owner|
...
```

When I step through the code I can see that `record[association_key_name]` is a BigDecimal e.g. 108.0, and when `to_s` is applied it becomes "108.0". However, the keys in the `owners_map` hash is expecting "108" not "108.0"

The `association_key_name` is the name of the foreign key in the Oracle database and is defined as type Number. The primary key is also defined as type Number, but strangely enough it doesn't resolve to a BigDecimal.

Any ideas? Is this a possible bug? Or does the precision on the database column need altered?

**System Info:**
JRuby on Rails (3.2.1)
ActiveRecord JDBC Adapter
Oracle Database (using views instead of tables)

Comment: Yeah, somehow the Number datatype in Oracle has precision > 0.  If Rails generated the column (defined as :integer) then this is probably a Rails bug.  If the table existed with a foreign key of type Number with precision > 0, then it's a bug ... or at least a problem waiting to happen.  Actually I guess it wouldn't be waiting any more :-).  I found this (ages old) with a quick google search: http://blog.rayapps.com/2007/11/16/some-issues-with-oracle-views-as-activerecord-source/

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'm actually using views to wrap tables so I'll look into getting the precision removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that the foreign key on the database was defined as Number with precision. Thanks to [tharrison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/414127/tharrison) for pointing me to [this](http://blog.rayapps.com/2007/11/16/some-issues-with-oracle-views-as-activerecord-source/) article.

I got our DBA to remove the precision on the field and everything worked fine. Of course, we are in the fortunate position of building a new product where our schema can be easily changed...

Comment: Issue still haunts jRuby, Oracle JDBC with Rails 4.1.5. Has anyone figure out a patch for new versions of JDBC